# Numbers storage issue

Tags: 16.04, lts, gnome-calculator

I see nobody has raised this question, so I'll raise it myself. How does one store numbers/results on this calculator? There is no **M+** button nor any similar memory buttons visible on the GUI. Nor is there any mention of how to do this under **Calculator Help**. Since 99% of calculators provide this very basic task, am I missing something???

Answer (score 1):

There is no default 'memory' button in the default 'basic' mode of the calculator.  Some *ultra basic* calculators off the shelf don't even have that mode.

But fear not, there *is* a memory function in Advanced Mode.  But, not the simple "Memory `+`/`-`/`Recall`" that calculators have.

I have an example there for how you would store something explicitly in a variable - `a = 10 + 20 + 30` is what I typed in, and it stored it in the variable `a`.  I also tested (not shown here, but it works) `10 + 20 + 30` which got me 60, and then afterwards did `a = ans`, and the `a` variable got the value of the last-executed command (`60`) and stored it in `a`.

[image]

[image]

Think of standard algebra with regards to this type of algebraic memory, and not the standard simple "M+" button from a basic calculator.  So you'd do some math and add it to memory by doing `a = a + ans` to get a 'new' memory value that has the prior mathematical value that was calculated added to it.

Comment: Thanks. I see that on basic format one can also assign variables to store values/results. I guess that's the approach to use here.

Answer (score 1):

You could install galculator, which has memory functions.

`sudo apt install galculator`

Then run:

`galculator`

[image]

Comment: Thnx. That looks like a good alternative.